# How to fix this SQL syntax error with MariaDB in nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mariadb

everyone I am new in node.js i developed a post-API, when I post data from postman by using form-data method I got this error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

here is the API code

```
const express = require('express');
const con = require('./config')
const app = express();
// app.use(express.json());
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./scheme and model/userSchema')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/register', async (req, resp) => {
   
    let data =new User(req.body) ;
    con.query('INSERT INTO test1 (name, number,type)', [data.name,data.number,data.type], (err, result, fields) => {
  
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            resp.status(202).json({
                status: 202,
                message: 'error in user data',
                error: err.sqlMessage,
            });

        }
        else {
            resp.status(200).json({ status: 200, message: 'user data store successfully', data: result, });
            resp.send(result);
          
            }
               

        

   
    console.log(req.body)
})
});

app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: Have a look at the [INSERT INTO](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_insert.asp) Statement and you should be able to figure out what you are missing which is half of the statement.

Comment: @Mushroomator , yes when I try this the API response is 200, but the data on MySQL is null
  let  sql ='INSERT INTO test1 (name, number, type) VALUES (`name`,number,type)';

Comment: `insert into thetable(col1, col2, col3) values(?, ?, ?)`